# Why convergence in Lp doesn't imply convergence almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory

I've been searching for an hour to find why convergence in Lp doesn't imply almost sure convergence. Can somebody explain why?

**EDIT**: I've read that Lp is not sufficient nor necessary for almost sure convergence!! I don't know why?

Comment: Check this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167218/why-does-l2-convergence-not-imply-almost-sure-convergence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does convergence in $L^p$ imply convergence almost everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-imply-convergence-almost-everywhere)

Answer (score 9):

The following example should illustrate why $L^p$ convergence doesn't imply  almost sure convergence.

Suppose we have a set of simple functions $\{X_n\}$ defined on $([0,1],\mathcal{B}[(0,1)],\lambda)$—where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure—in this way: 
$$X_1=1_{\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]}, \ X_2=1_{\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]},\\
X_3=1_{\left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right]}, \ X_4=1_{\left[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right]}, \ X_5=1_{\left[\frac{2}{3},1\right]},$$
etc etc etc. For any $p>0$,
$$\mathbb E(|X_1|^p)=\frac{1}{2}, \ E(|X_2|^p)=\frac{1}{2}, 
\\ E(|X_3|^p)=\frac{1}{3}, \ E(|X_4|^p)=\frac{1}{3},\ ...,\ E(|X_6|^p)=\frac{1}{4},\ ...$$
So $\mathbb E(|X_n|^p) \to 0$ and $X_n \stackrel{L^p}\rightarrow 0$. However, $X_n \not\to 0$ almost surely: for any $\omega \in [0,1]$, $X_n(\omega)=1$ for infinitely many n, and so $X_n \not\to 0$. $\>\square$

Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: For further reference, some people call this type of sequence a "typewriter sequence". The reason is that it looks like a text cursor (caret) moving from left to right and then returning to the beginning when the end is reached.