# do measurable functions with values in SO(3) a.e. form a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose set $\cal{M}=\{f \mbox{ such that }f\,:\,[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}\mbox{ is measurable and }f(t)\in\mathrm{SO(3)}\mbox{ almost enywhere}\}$.

Is this set closed and why?

If not, please name some possibly minor modifications of the definition that make $\cal{M}$ closed.

I had a in real analysis on a graduate level few years ago, but can not comprehend this now.

Comment: Closed in what sense? Are you putting some topology on the space of measureable functions and want to know if $\mathcal{M}$ is a closed subset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more thinking and referencing Royden's Real Analysis book I think I got it. The answer is that I have to first introduce topology and then with the right topology the answer is yes, it closed.

A set is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points.

Actually, as both the domain and the codomain are essentialy finite, thus all measurable functions are in this case integrable. Thus set-wise ${\cal M}=L^1(0,1;SO(3))$ and so let us take the topology from $L^1$.

For $1 ≤ p ≤ ∞$, by $L^1(0,1;\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3})$ is a Banach space by the Riesz-Fischer theorem.

Thus, I need only to prove that the limit $f$ of convergent sequence $(f_n)\in\cal{M}$ has its values almost anywhere in SO(3).

See [Does convergence in $L^{p}$ implies convergence almost everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere) It is mentioned that for every sequence converging in $L^p$ there is a subsequence converging pointwise a.e. I call such subsequence in my case $f_j$.

On the other hand SO(3) is closed subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and so almost everywhere f stays on SO(3).