# Example of Converge in measure, but not converge point-wise a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

Can anyone give an exam of Converge in measure, but not converge point-wise a.e.?

And also for the converse part, professor asks us to prove "pointwise a.e. implies converge in measure", but think about this function:

$$f_n(x)= \chi_{[n,\infty)}$$

It converge to $f(x)=0$ pointwise, but it seems that the difference measure between $f(x)$ and $f_n(x)$ is always infinity.

Comment: I guess there's a premise that the functions are integrable.

Comment: Look at Counterexamples in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure.

Comment: For the second part, your counter example is fine.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/138043/8271)

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, consider the [typewriter sequence](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/) (Example 4).

Answer (score 2):

for the first part :take $f_n$ on $[0,1]$ as $1_{E_{n}}$ and $E_{n}$are  like this sequance
$E_{1}= [0,\frac{1}{2}) E_{2}= [\frac{1}{2},1]$
$E_{3}= [0,\frac{1}{3}) E_{4}= [\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}] E_{5}= [\frac{2}{3},1]$
...

and for your other qustion the theorem is true whene $f_{n}$ has finite domain.