# Does $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}f_{m}\left(x\right) $ converge for almost every $x$ in $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let {$f_{m}$} be a sequence of measureable real-valued functions in $\left(X,\mathrm{\mathcal{M}},\mu\right)$. Suppose ${\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left\{ {\displaystyle \int_{X}\left|f_{m}\right|^{9}d\mu}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{9}}}<\infty
>  $. Does $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}f_{m}\left(x\right)
>  $ converge for almost every $x$ in $X$?

I have no idea. Help me some hints.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** The answer is yes. (I hope it isn't from a multiple choice test and I just gave the entire thing away.)

**Hint 2:** Consider the functions $g_m = \lvert f_m\rvert$ and $G_n = \sum\limits_{m=1}^n g_m$. Use Minkowski's inequality (the triangle inequality) and monotone convergence.

**Hint 3:** Absolute convergence implies convergence.

> Let $S = \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \lVert f_m\rVert_9$. By assumption $S < \infty$, and for all $n$ we have $$\lVert G_n\rVert_9 \leqslant \sum_{m=1}^n\lVert g_m\rVert_9 = \sum_{m=1}^n \lVert f_m\rVert_9 \leqslant S.$$ $(G_n)$ is a monotone sequence of non-negative functions, and so is $(G_n^9)$, so the pointwise limit $G(x) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} G_n(x)$ exists ($[0,\infty]$-valued), and the monotone convergence theorem tells us $$\int_X G(x)^9\,d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X G_n(x)^9\,d\mu \leqslant S^9 < \infty.$$ Since $G^9$ is integrable, $N = \{ x : G(x) = +\infty\}$ is a $\mu$-null set. On $X\setminus N$ we have $\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \lvert f_m(x)\rvert < \infty$, that is, $\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty f_m(x)$ converges *absolutely* almost everywhere. A fortiori, $\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty f_m(x)$ converges almost everywhere (to a finite limit).

Comment: Does convergence in $L^9$ imply pointwise convergence?

Comment: So maybe the answer is no

Comment: @chuyenvien94 Convergence in $L^9$ does not imply pointwise convergence, only that a subsequence exists that converges pointwise everywhere, but that is usually proved in the way I propose. The sequence to consider here has special properties that guarantee that in this case $L^9$ convergence implies pointwise convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: I need more details. Can you make your hints more precise?

Comment: I've added one more thing to the hints, I hope that helps.

Comment: I still dont get your idea.  The sequence {$h_{n}$}$=\Sigma$${f_{i}}$ converge to $h$ implies that a subsequence {$h_{n_{k}}
 $} converge pointwise to $h$, but how can we conclude that the whole sequence is pointwise convergent?

Comment: Forget about $f_m$ for the moment. Consider only $g_m$ and $G_n$ first. From that you get the result about $\sum f_m$ with hint 3.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not in general. But you can always find an almost everywhere pointwise convergent subsequence.

See [Does convergence in $L^{p}$ implies convergence almost everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere)

Comment: We are looking at the sum of a sequence where the sum of norms converges. That implies the pointwise a.e. convergence of the sum.