# Simple $L^p$ space question

Tags: lp-spaces

Let $X$ be a measure space with positive measure $\mu$.

If $\|f_n-f\|_p\to 0$ (i.e. $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the $L^p(\mu)$ norm) does it follow that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ almost everywhere?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere