# Generalized Fourier series in $L^2$ that do not converge pointwise a.e.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

For a Hilbert space $L^2$ we have the notion of an orthonormal basis $\{f_j\}$ being a sequence of orthonormal elements such that any element $f$ in $L^2$ can be approximated by partial sums in terms of this basis
$$f = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \langle f, f_j \rangle f_j$$
Here the sum converges wrt the $L^2$ norm.  This is what I mean by generalized Fourier series.

I have been reading about [Carleson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem) that says specifically for Fourier series, the series converges pointwise almost everywhere to the approximated function.  I have also read that this is not true for a general orthonormal basis.  I was hoping someone would be able to provide me with an example demonstrating that statement on a finite measure space, maybe $L^2([0,1])$: A function whose partial sums in terms of the basis do not convergence pointwise almost everywhere.

Comment: Here is something similar to yours: http://mathoverflow.net/q/209900/75968

Comment: Of interest is Definition 8 and Theorem 11 from section 7 of  [this paper](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Price.pdf).

Comment: Section 9 of the paper linked above gives an example of what you want, I think.

Comment: The paper recommended by @DavidMitra says in page 602 that Zahorski in 1960 asserted the existence of an $L^2$ function whose Fourier series could be re-arranged to diverge a.e. If you take $f$ to be that function and the $f_j$ that particular rearrangement of the Fourier base, then I think you have your counter-example.

Comment: You can find classical results about this in Garcia _Topics in Almost Everywhere Convergence_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the comments.  I was able to use them to provide an answer to [When does $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$ exist for random sequences $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375925/when-does-sum-i-1-infty-x-i-exist-for-random-sequences-x-i-i-1/1375944#1375944).  I'll restate the result from there as it provides an example:

Consider the measure space $L^2([0,1])$ with uniform lebesgue measure.
Define the functions (Haar functions) $f_{2^i + k}$ by 
$$f_{2^i + k} = 2^{i/2}\chi_{\left[\frac{k}{2^i}, \frac{k+1/2}{2^i}\right]} - 2^{i/2}\chi_{\left[\frac{k + 1/2}{2^i}, \frac{k+1}{2^i}\right]}$$
for $i \geq 1, 0 \leq k < 2^i$.

On pg. 598 of the paper mentioned in the comments: [Topics in Orthogonal Functions - Price](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Price.pdf) the author states the Haar functions defined above form a complete orthonormal basis.  Then pg. 603 of the paper states

> For every complete orthonormal system $\Phi$ there is an $L^2$ function $g$ whose $\Phi$-Fourier series can be rearranged to diverge almost everywhere.

So we can finish as follows.  Take the Haar functions as above (a complete orthonormal set) and the function $g$ defined above.  We write this function's $\Phi$-Fourier series as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle g, f_n \rangle f_n$$
Now there exists a rearrangement $\sigma$ of the indices of the sum such that it diverges almost everywhere.  Now let $g_n = \langle g, f_{\sigma(n)} \rangle f_{\sigma(n)}$ be this rearrangement of terms.  The sum $\sum g_n$ diverges almost everywhere.

Comment: One might mention that in the linked paper, a specific permutation of the Haar basis, and a sketch of a proof that that it "works", is given.

Comment: What does your notation $\chi_{[a,b]}$ mean? And what is "the function $g$ defined above"?

Comment: $\chi_{[a, b]}$ is the indicator function of the set $[a,b]$.  It is $1$ for $x$ in the set and $0$ otherwise.  $g$ is defined the highlighted text - "an $L^2$  function whose $\Phi$-Fourier can be rearranged to diverge almost everywhere."

Comment: Ah, thanks, I missed the definition of $g$.

Comment: So the function sequence of partial sums $h_n(x)$ is Cauchy w.r.t. the $L^2$ norm, but the real sequence $h_n(x_0)$ is not Cauchy for any fixed $x_0$?

Comment: Regardless of the rearrangement, the $L^2$ norm exists and is the same - so yes, it is cauchy wrt to that.  If by $h_n$ you mean the sequence of partial sums given by rearrangement such that it "diverges almost everywhere" then your second statement is almost accurate.  There is a measure zero set such that the sequence does converge pointwise.