# Strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $X_i\in\mathcal{L}^2$ with expectation $0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]/i^2<\infty$ and suppose they are pairwise non correlated. Does then the SLLN still hold?

Comment: Maybe(?) related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375925/when-does-sum-i-1-infty-x-i-exist-for-random-sequences-x-i-i-1#comment2802355_1375925

Comment: I don't have any answer ready yet but if $\sum \frac{X_i}{i}$ converges a.s. then SLLN follows from Kronecker's Lemma as $n \uparrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to impose just uncorrelatedness between the variables in the sequence rather than independence, then you need to impose a stronger condition than  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} Var[X_i]/i^2 < \infty$. To be more precise, a sufficient condition in this case that will guarantee SLLN is the following: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} Var[X_i] \left(\frac{log \, i}{i}\right)^2 < \infty.$$

This follows from Serlfing's SLLN.