# Does $L^2$-convergence of test functions imply a.e. convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose I have a sequence $f_n\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ of compactly supported smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$ (with values in $\mathbb{R}$) that converge in the $L^2$-norm to $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Then does $f_n$ converge pointwise almost-everywhere to $f$?

(Actually I have in mind the case when $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is replaced by $H^2(M)$, the second Sobolev space on a non-compact manifold, but I thought that perhaps this would follow from the simpler case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general this is false. Luckily though there exist subsequences which converge a.e. pointwise.

See for instance this question [Lp convergence and pointwise convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere). The countexample in there is given in terms of characteristic functions, you could get one for smooth functions by approximating those.

Answer (score 1):

No always, but we can find a subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$ that converges to $f$ pointwise a.e.