# Multiresolution Analysis scaling function

Tags: functional-analysis, wavelets

Given a multiresolution analysis $(V_j)_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}$ in $L²(ℝ)$ with scaling function $\varphi \in L²(ℝ)$. As $(2^{1/2}\varphi(2t-k))_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V_1$ and $\varphi \in V_0\subseteq V_1$ 
we have 
$$\varphi(t)= \sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}^{}\langle\varphi, 2^{1/2}\varphi(2t-k)\rangle 2^{1/2}\varphi(2t-k).$$
This equation is called scaling equation. Does this equation hold for almost every $t\in ℝ$? And if yes, why?

Comment: If $(e_k)$ is an orthonromal basis of a Hilbert space $V$, then for each $f\in V$ we have $f = \sum_k\langle f,e_k\rangle e_k$.

Comment: So does it hold almost everywhere or not? Because sometimes I can read this!

Comment: Hmm, I doubt it because a celebrated result by Carleson says that this is true if $(e_k)$ is the Fourier basis. Here, the basis is rather arbitrary.

Comment: Then I don't understand the pages 153 and 154 here (https://books.google.de/books?id=EUH4DQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: At the beginning of the page 154 it says that this scaling equation holds for almost every $t\in ℝ$. Thats exact the opposite what you have said.

Comment: Equality is as elements of $L^2$. Which means that the points of difference form a set of measure zero. So the equality is almost everywhere.

Comment: What they mean is not that the series converges for a.e. $t$. You have to understand the series as an $L^2$-limit $g$, so $\phi = g$ in $L^2$ and that means equality almost everywhere.

Comment: ahhh thank you, but it is wrong to say, if $g$ is the series, that $\varphi(t)=g(t)$ for almost every t holds?

Comment: No, that's correct. But it's wrong that $\phi(t) = \sum_ka_k\phi_k(t)$ for a.e. $t$ (where the series is a different one for each $t$).

Comment: But where is there the difference? It is just somehow renaming the series  with a different letter. I don't get it. But thank you so far!

Comment: $L^p$ convergence implies pointwise almost everywhere convergence of a subsequence, not the original sequence per se.

Comment: See here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere

Comment: The scaling equation on the Fourier side but holde in L² sense and almost everywhere because of Carlsons theorem or?