# Finite norm of sequence implies convergence of sequence?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

Consider an $L^p(X)$ space, for example a probability space. Suppose that I have a sequence of function $x_n\in X$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \lVert x_n\rVert_p<\infty$. Does this imply that $\{x_n\}_{n}^\infty$ converge to an $x\in X$ under the same norm? If not what are the typical conditions to suffice this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-imply-convergence-almost-everywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not. A simple example is to look at the standard basis $\{e_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ for $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Then $$\lVert e_n\rVert_2 = 1 $$ but the sequence does not converge to anything.

Comment: thanks for the example!

Comment: @EdonRon An addition to this answer: Not only that, but $\{e_n\}$ doesn't even have a convergent subsequence. In particular, not every closed and bounded set is compact.