# If $X_n(\omega )\overset{L^2}{\rightarrow}X(\omega )$ and g(x) is continuous and bounded so $g(X_n(\omega ))\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}g(X(\omega ))$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, lp-spaces, pointwise-convergence

Let a sequence of r.v. $X_n(\omega )\overset{L^2}{\rightarrow}X(\omega )$ and $g(x)$ a continuous bounded function.
Is this implies ,and if yes can you please give the prove, that $g(X_n(\omega ))\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}g(X(\omega ))$

Comment: What did you try? Add that in an edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does convergence in $L^p$ imply convergence almost everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-imply-convergence-almost-everywhere)

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks for your answer but NO i allready know that for exemple the typewriter sequence fct is a counter exemple that converge in L2 but doesn't converge point wise (no where).  
I m speaking in a special case when g(x) is bounded. I ve yesterday heard about this theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem that can help me answer my question. But sadly i ve an exam soon and i can't spend too much time on it. I ll maybe try to writte a full and details answer to my question (based on this theorem) when i ll have more time, and if i succeed to do it of course.

Comment: Oh, I missed that detail. Close vote retracted.

Comment: Somebody can help me?

Comment: Anyone to help me?